# EXCEL:VBA Getting Set ActiveX componet can't create object for imacro?

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, imacros, vba

I am running imacro from excel vba im getting ActiveX componet can't create object while creating object

```
Set iim1 = CreateObject("imacros")
```

For reference imacro, I can't find anything in folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Ipswitch\iMacros
```

And also I have searched iimInterface.dll but not found in the above path.

But I have download iimInterface.dll form website copied in that path and register the that dll in regsvr32 after that im getting "object doesn't support this property or method " in

```
iret = iim1.iimOpen("IE")
```